# can't set Python.h file path in macOS

Tags: python, c

I saw a lot of posts here like my problem and tried every solution up here so i gave up. even on the internet there are solutions for linux and windows but i couldn't solve mine. anyways my problem is that i'm trying to write a basic extension in c for python, but in vscode i have to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h>
```

but what i want to do is just

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
```

so obviously writing a really long file path doesn't seem appealing. i tried to do

```
export 
C_INCLUDE_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10"
```

and some derivatives of it in the ~/.bash_profile but none has worked for me so far.

Comment: Your example calls `export` with no arguments, then defines a shell variable. That should be one line: `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=...`

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using `bash`, and not `zsh`? If you are using `zsh`, then `.zprofile` is the file to edit, not `.bash_profile`. There's also the issue that VS Code is not using *any* shell's environment, so you'll have to make this setting in VS Code itself somewhere. (I don't use VS Code myself.)

Comment: no, i'm using bash. also that solved my problem. thank you.